# How to access a service in docker-compose from another sevice

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am new to docker and I want to know how to connect via localhost to one service from another.
For, example when I create a service and if I want to access it from the host machine then I just give a port mapping in docker-compose like

`-8080:80`

and then I do `localhost:8080` in host machine to connect to it. My question is how do I connect when I want to do it from inside another docker service or container. What mapping do i do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets say you installed docker on windows host. In docker-compose for every service you give a port mapping. For ex. for a service named service1 you do

```
service1: 
     ports:
        -9001:9000
```

Here 9000 is the port in the service1 that you want to map. This port is mapped to port 9001 of host windows.
Now you access service1 from windows using -> `localhost:9001`

You access service1 from another service inside docker using -> `service1:9000`

Now, to answer your question, you can do something like following

```
service1:
    ports:
       -9001:9000

service2:
    ports:
       -9002:9000
```

access service1 from host windows -> `localhost:9001`

access service2 from host windows -> `localhost:9002`

access service1 from inside docker -> `service1:9000`

access service2 from inside docker -> `service2:9000`